# Combining outcomes in multinomial logit in r

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, logistic, categorical-data, multinomial-distribution

Suppose, I have nominal dependent variable with 4 categories 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'. I estimate multinomial logit model and want to test hypothesis, that, for example, categories 'C' and 'D' are  indistinguishable with respect to the independent variables in the model. I know that it is possible with the help of LR and Wald tests, but I haven't find implementation of them for such type of hypothesis in R (I've tried to find it in different packages which provide multinomial logit ('nnet','mlogit','mclogit').

Do you know examples of implemtation or how to do it manually?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, now I see what you mean. I think you can do that easily on `stata` (using spost13 commands) but I am not sure there is an implementation in `R`.